# sql vs hashtable.containskey vs string.contains

Tags: c#, t-sql, string, hashtable

I have a list of values extracted from a sql query in order to find out if x provided values are present in it.

```
SQL:
  -Select null from table where code='x'
  -resul.count>0

String:
  -Loop for concatenating the codes in one string
  -codesstring.Contains("x")

Hashtable:
  -Loop for adding the codes to the hashtable
  -codeshashtable.ContainsKey("x")
```

The list will be in the thousands range...whats the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check if value is present, method `Contains` of class `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` return result faster then the same method of `Hashtable`. See Benchmark result: http://dotnetperls.com/hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

Only the SQL will prevent the entire result set from being transferred from the DB to your app.  At that point, it depends (a little) on how often you are doing these checks.  If you have lots and lots and lots of values to check, then I'd go with the hashtable and cache the entire list in memory.

The string lookup is going to be a poor performer in any scenario.

Comment: I'd vote for the hashtable.  The sql table is only doing an index-covered query anyways, so functionally what is the difference?  Anyways a well-thought answer.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you, but the fastest way would be to just retrieve the count itself:

```
select count(*) 
from MyTable 
where code = 'x'
```

Answer (score -1):

You do NOT ask for the same in query 1 and 2.

Strng would be

> codestring.Equals ('x')

What is the fastest depends. String loop: no

Hashtable - yes, for thousands already loaded (i.e. you dont have to hit the database)

Otherwise directly database.

Comment: codestring.Equals('x') would return false always as the string is the concatenated codes...

Comment: So would the sql then that you give with "where code='x'" - it wold also return false.

Comment: "where code='x'" queries a table of values (multiple rows, multiple codes, example, code='a', code='b', and so forth).  Doing codestring.Equals('x') will evaluates a single value ('x') against a single string (example: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').  They are completely different.